# POP server timing out on a slow connection

Tags: email, thunderbird, pop3, timeout

If a POP server is giving a `Time Out` error, due to a slow connection, can any options be modified as to take that into account, and (hopefully somehow) collect mail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Head over to Tools -> Options -> Advanced and change the value of “Connection timeout” to a value which suits you.</s>

To change timeout, you need to go to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced`. Select `General` in the `Advanced` pane. The `Config Editor` button is on the bottom right. Now type `mailnews.tcptimeout` and then change to whatever you need it.

( [via](http://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/no_way_to_increase_connection_timeout_in_thunderbird_3) )

Comment: Thunderbird 3 ?? I don't seem to be able to find anything similar to "connection timeout" in Advanced.

Comment: @Idig updated .

Comment: @Idigas Good to know. You're welcome!